# Survival analysis of two dependent variables (hatching time and total life duration)

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I strive to find the best approach to analyse survival data from an experiment where random samples of fish eggs (sample size 30) were put into 3 different solutions of 8 heavy metals (total 24 combinations solution x metal plus one control group).

For each egg the hatching time (in hours) was recorded (for eggs that was not already dead). Further, in case where an egg was successfully hatched, skeletal problems and total lifetime (up to 96 hours) were recorded (one observation every 6 hours, up to 96 hours).

Hatching time survival analysis was rather straightforward using Kaplan Meier estimator and log - rank tests in order to find homogeneous metals for each solution subgroup. As a partial result some metals were recognized as more toxic than the others.

However, total lifetime is obviously dependent to hatching time (and hatching event) as well as on skeletal problems after hatch. Since there is more than one independent variables to explain life duration, Kaplan Meier is not an appropriate choice and Cox regression should be applied.

A choice is to consider life duration *after* hatching event as the dependent variable and run a Cox regression having metal solution and skeletal problems as explaining variables. However, this model seems to be a poor choice since it seems natural to expect that the exposure of the egg to the toxic environment before hatch will also affect the total life duration.

So, a question arises.

What could be the best approach in order to model the lifetime duration? Is the above choice (life duration after hatch) the only possible approach or there is a more sophisticated procedure to follow in order to model the total burden that a fish accepts from the metal environment? In case of an affirmative answer what is the suggested procedure in R or SPSS to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why not use the total lifetime duration? (including the hatching period)

Comment: This is a choice but I am sceptic because in that way I do not take into account the time where hatching event was happened something that could have an effect to the final life duration.

Comment: You could do total lifetime and put hatched/not hatched into the model as time-dependent covariate to account for immortal time bias (https://dancingbiostatistician.wordpress.com/2016/03/18/immortal-time-bias/)

Comment: Unfortunately I already submitted this study. Finally, I applied a Cox model using the total lifetime duration as the dependent variable. Nevertheless, thank you for your comment and your linked post